# How to bind C# generated button to XAML MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So far I have read a lot about binding and I have looked up my question. Unfortunately the questions I stumbled upon, were questions regarding the CONTENT of a button.

My question rather is:

How can I bind a C# generated button (`new Button (//CONTENT)`) to my XAML, rather then just binding content to my already generated button?

in my MVVM code I have property which holds a button as value called `RequestedButton`, but I have no idea as to what kind of tag I should use in my XAML to bind this property to.

I do know how to bind this if it were to be a `ObservableCollection`, but no idea on how to bind it if it's a single attribute.

So my question (to the point) is: What kind of element should I use in my XAML, to use the binding on for the property `RequestedButton`, to use `{Binding RequestedButton}` on?

In my class I have a property named `RequestedButton`, which holds a Button as a value. Like this:

```
Class Foo
{
   public Button RequestedButton {get; set;}

   public Foo()
   {
       RequestedButton = new Button()//GENERATE BUTTON WITH PROPERTIES IN IT
   }
}
```

What tag should I now use, to correctly display (use `Binding`) the button ABOVE in my XAML?

Comment: are you asking how to bind a complete Button object generated in code to your XAML?

Comment: absolutely no idea what youre saying, Youre question title is something different from question body

Comment: What is `RequestedButton` ? a property or a command ? If you want to bind an action to the button click you should create a command on your vm, call that action on your command and bind the button Command property to the command on your vm.

Please explain better and paste some code to better understanding

Comment: @Jason Yes... This is exactly what I meant, but I wasn't entirely sure how to describe it as good as possible.

Comment: @DOM you have a `Button RequestedButton = new Button()` and now you want it in XAML? is that it?

Comment: you can use a ContentView and bind it's Content property to the Button object - I think this will work.

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi Yes. I have indeed generated the button like that (MVVM), and now I would like to use a tag to use {Binding RequestedButton} on. I do not know what tag this would be. According to Jason this is ContentView.

Comment: If you bind to a UI element than it's not MVVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View Model

```
private Button requestedButton = new Button();
public Button RequestedButton
{
    get
    {
        return requestedButton;
    }
    set
    {
        requestedButton = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(RequestedButton));
    }
}
...
```

Xaml

```
<ContentView Content="{Binding RequestedButton}"/>
```